# laravel how to set class according to a message

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have a dropdown and I have styled it in a way that the current opened `li` is colored red.

This dropdown menu locates at the left of the page. and this menu exist in all pages.

All pages just set the content of other div in the page but the menu is always for all of them (I hope you get me).

In the controller I do this:

```
return View::make('restaurants.admins')->with('admin', $admin)->with('verticalMenu' , 'Admin');
```

So in the view I want to check this `verticalMenu` value, if it is `admin`, I will set admin's `li` class to `open class`  and so on.

I will show you an example of what I want.

#### this is li that is closed

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:;">
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Restaurant <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <!-- more html here -->
</li>
```

#### This is li that is opened because it has the class open

```
<li class="dropdown active opened">
    <a href="javascript:;">
        <i class="fa fa-tasks"></i> Profile <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <!-- more html here -->
</li>
```

So basically, I need to check the `{{$verticalMenu}}` **before each li, right?**, if yes, how please? if no, what is the correct way please?

#### After your answer

This is the mistake page, please look how the profile li is opened:

![Screen shot of the actual page][1]

This is the good one, where everything is perfect:

Comment: Can you add the html code you get when you view source from the web browser too?

Comment: @Unnawut okay I will add it in a jsfilddle because the code will not be small but it is so easy don't worry

Comment: @Unnawut here we go http://jsfiddle.net/89CcT/

Comment: @Unnawut there is no error, right? :)

Comment: Your code looks fine. I don't think there's a problem with your Laravel/PHP code. Probably something along the line that @KyleK mentioned.

Comment: @Unnawut I will post another question, many thanks for the efforts

Comment: Your jsfiddle and it's output looks perfectly fine in my browser. I don't get two lists opened at the same time. So I guess it's all fixed right? Congrats!

Comment: @Unnawut no no my friend, the jsfiddle gives two opened lists. check again :)

Comment: Your `.sub-nav` class for Profile dropdown has `style="display: block;"` in it. Remove that style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{{ }}` basically turns a code like this:

```
{{ $verticalMenu }}
```

Into this:

```
<?php echo $verticalMenu; ?>
```

What you are trying to achieve is this:

```
<?php echo $verticalMenu == 'Admin' ? 'active opened' : '' ?>
```

So the most straight-forward way to do it with blade syntax is:

```
<li class="dropdown {{ $vericalMenu == 'Admin' ? 'active opened' : '' }}">
    <!-- The rest of the list content here -->
</li>
```

Comment: your answer helps me `90%`, but I have a problem that when a specific page is open, the `profile` li is keep opening, can I show you the code in jsfiddle?

Comment: Since it's still related to your question, try make an edit with the extra code. :)

Comment: I added two images for that. if you need more code tell me please? though I know you will need right?

Comment: Seems like a css class issue now, you probably have an extra `opened` or `active` class somewhere in your code that's breaking it.

Comment: no I don't have that. I posted the whole code for you. could you check please? appreciate your time

Comment: the problem in code happens on this **li** `<li class="dropdown {{ $verticalMenu == 'Profile' ? 'active opened' : '' }}">`

Comment: you may have some javascript menu filter being applied on pageloads which is probably setting your menues active classes

Comment: @KyleK I do have a javascript but just on click and on the `open active` class